# Using signals for update chessboard using client server TCP/IP sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

let's suppose I have to develop a simple chess game using client server tcp/ip sockets in C.

Two clients gets connected to a server which manages their movements and their game.

My program works properly.

Unfortunately, I am not able to see my opponent's move until I move a chess of mine, so that the chessboard gets updated.

How can I automatically update the chessboard?

Maybe should I use signals or something similar?

Comment: Don't bother using signals, ever.

Comment: When one player makes a move, the client tells the server what move it's making. Then the server either tells the other client what move was made, or tells it what the board looks like. Then the other client displays it on the screen. How much of it is working so far?